# How to generate component in angular library with multiple entry points?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have an **angular** project with a multiple entry points library.

For a single entry point library, I can generate new components by adding `project` param like:

```
ng g module/newComponent --project ngx-eska-theme
```

The new component will be added to: `projects/ngx-eska-theme/src/lib/module/new-component` where the `angular.json` options like:

```
"sourceRoot": "projects/ngx-eska-theme/src"
```

My question is:

I have multiple entry points in that package, so how can I use `angular/cli` for the right entry point without changing the "sourceRoot" every time?

I tried to set it to be "projects/ngx-eska-theme", but it will add the component to `lib` folder instead of `src`.

[image: Project files]

[image: angular.json]